# PHP insert include into dynamic text - two dynamic elements, will it still execute?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have an interesting question, or atleast I think it is.

I have this website http://21-card-games.com/best/casino-reviews/casino-casino-titan.asp. You will see the image and below it the content.

Is it possible to combine the image with the text and left align the image and make the text flow next to the image.

The pages are all dynamically created, The content on the page is a variable that I import from a mysql db...

Here is some of the coding:

```
<div id="yui-main"><div class="yui-b"><?php echo $g_page_content2 ?><br />
      <?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/includes/standard_images_screenshot_1.php');?><?php echo $g_content_text1 ?>
      <?php /* This is the second banner for this page */ include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/includes/banners/'.$row_rs_settings['g_sites_affiliate_ads2'].'.php');?></div>
```

The $g_content_text1 is the variable that pulls in the text, and the '/includes/standard_images_screenshot_1.php' is the image. The include image file is part of a script that creates the image on the fly (imagick).

However this is more or less what I where thinking:

to create a regex that replaces the first occurance of `<p>` with this `include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/includes/banners/'.$row_rs_settings['g_sites_affiliate_ads2'].'.php'` but I am not sure if the php will still execute if I do that...

Any ideas on how I can accomplish this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get it.
Why you want to create a regexp to let the text flow on the left of the image?
This is a css issue.
Just add float:left to the image.

Comment: will it work, even if there is a paragraph between the image code and the text <img src="http://21-card-games.com/images/5-reel-slots/adventurepalace.jpg" width="300" /><p>Adventure Palace is an fantast

Comment: lol!!! It works - Thanks a million - I have not done this for years! - I have confused tables and paragraph elements for very long... Did not think it were this easy, and would have created a very complicated work around!